# Having Trouble with 3d Models from Blender Into Three js

Tags: three.js, blender

[GiF Of what I'm Experiencing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWAec.gif) When i use dat.gui the x and z coordinate are both doing the same thing, also I changed the color of the 3 model and imported it and my model is still black?

```
[import { GLTFLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader';

const gltfLoader = new GLTFLoader()


gltfLoader.load('./CellPhone_IP6.gltf', (gltf) => {
    
    gltf.scene.scale.set(0.3, 0.3, 0.3)
        gltf.scene.rotation.set(0, 5, 0);

    scene.add(gltf.scene)

    gui.add(gltf.scene.rotation,'x').min(-10).max(9)
    gui.add(gltf.scene.rotation,'y').min(-10).max(9)
    gui.add(gltf.scene.rotation,'z').min(-10).max(9)
});
```

Ive tried restarting my dev Env

looking for finished project code to troubleshoot

Restarting the Tutorial From Scratch
[Tutorial[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qi7WX.gif)

Comment: Your model is black because you have most likely not added any lights to your scene. Try it with an ambient and directional light. Besides, before exporting from Blender, make sure to properly center models at the origin.

Comment: Thanks both of those things worked, but the x and z controls are still doing the same thing any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Without a debugging option it will be hard to investigate this issue. Consider to share a live example. https://jsfiddle.net/vy29n6aj/